# Is there a clean approach to justify text in Reporting Service?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, text, reporting-services

I'm creating a Report using SQL Reporting Services and I need to justify the text inside a textbox. By justify a mean aligning the text to both margin, left AND right. Just like justifying text in MS Word.

I've been browsing a lot and found only a few smelly solutions.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Thanks,

Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that there is not a direct way to do this at the moment, although it is on the development team's radar.

Comment: I find it surprising that an 'Enterprise' Microsoft product doesn't not support this SSRS2008. Hopefully it's not too far away.

Comment: And once again the Oh-So-Powerful We-Know-It-All SO mods have rejected my edit, an edit which only has one goal: to increase the number of votes on a feature request that is **directly related** to the question!  Is that spam? I think not! Here's the link to the MS Connect item, in case anyone cares about this feature: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/404966/full-justification-in-reporting-services-2008-needed